# Query simplification based on selected columns

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to understand how PostgreSQL simplifies a query: let's say I have 2 tables ("tb_thing" and "tb_thing_template"), where each thing points to a template, and that I run a query like this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    tb_thing.id
FROM
    tb_thing,
    tb_thing_template
WHERE
    tb_thing_template.id = tb_thing.template_id
;
```

This is the result:

```
                                   QUERY PLAN                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=34.75..64.47 rows=788 width=4)
   Hash Cond: (tb_thing.template_id = tb_thing_template.id)
   ->  Seq Scan on tb_thing  (cost=0.00..18.88 rows=788 width=8)
   ->  Hash  (cost=21.00..21.00 rows=1100 width=4)
         ->  Seq Scan on tb_thing_template  (cost=0.00..21.00 rows=1100 width=4)
```

The planner is joining the two tables even if I'm just selecting one field from "tb_thing" and nothing from "tb_thing_template".  I was hoping the planner was smart enough to figure out it didn't need to actually join the "tb_thing_template" table because I'm not selecting anything from it.

Why does it do the join anyway?  Why isn't the column selection taken into account when the query is planned?

Thanks!

Comment: But you **are** making a join. an **implicit join** the query planner is doing what you asked it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically your query and a simple `SELECT tb_thing.id FROM tb_thing` are not the same.

Assume, for instance, that table `tb_thing_template` has 4 rows with an identical `id` value that is also a `tb_thing.template_id`. The result of your query will then have 4 rows with the same `tb_thing.id`. Inversely, if a `tb_thing.template_id` is not present in `tb_thing_template.id` then that row will not be output.

Only when `tb_thing_template.id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` (so unique) and `tb_thing.template_id` is a `FOREIGN KEY` to that `id` with just a single row for each `PRIMARY KEY`, so a 1:1 relationship, are both queries semantically the same. Even a 1:N relationship, which is more typical in a PK-FK relationship, would require the join in a semantic sense. But the planner has no way of knowing if the relationship is 1:1, so you get the join.

But you should not try to spoof the query planner; it is smart, but not necessarily smarter than you (might be) dumb.

Comment: I forgot the definitions of the tables, which are as you say (keeping only the relevant fields):  CREATE TABLE tb_thing_template ( id serial PRIMARY KEY );  CREATE TABLE tb_thing ( id serial  PRIMARY KEY, template_id integer REFERENCES tb_thing_template NOT NULL );
I understand the first condition, but what do you mean with "with just a single row for each PRIMARY KEY"?  Thanks.